# SQL Query to Display Two Values for a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I am trying to write a SQL query that will display the store, ID, MAC and AppName for any device that contains the apps "iMobilePOS" and "StoreFulfill" in the AppName columns.  I am very very close...what I am trying to do is display only two lines for each of those devices.  One containing the "iMobile" AppName value, and the other containing the "StoreFill" AppName value.  Currently, the results are displaying a line for every single app the device has installed...here is my query for reference:

```
SELECT DISTINCT storenumber, 
                registerid, 
                wifi_mac, 
                appname 
FROM   mpos_health.dbo.mdat_data_report AS mdat 
       INNER JOIN mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
               ON mdat.wifi_mac = mpos.wifimac 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
               WHERE  mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
                      AND appname = 'iMobilePOS') 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
                   WHERE  mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
                          AND appname = 'StoreFulfill');
```

I am joining the two tables because they both have information I want to include, and their common value is the WiFiMAC of the device.  This query is filtering devices the way I would want, but it is including all applications.  For example, here is what I am seeing currently:

[image]

Where, I would not want to see the second line for MobileIron, I would only want to see the other two lines.  Containing iMobilePOS and StoreFulfill.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Comment: For the love of god - please format your SQL instead of having it in one giant line

Comment: Can you show your source data and the desired output for this query?

Comment: @AbeMiessler you could just ask nicely, and unfortunately I cannot include the source data.  The desired output - I gave an example in my OP, of what is being returned and what I would want to see.

Comment: I did it for you.  Sorry if you were offended.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I just noticed an error in my explanation - corrected above, hopefully it makes more sense now. :)

Comment: Personally I"d refactor it all but to finish off your query as is simply add a `AND AppName in ('StoreFulFill','iMobilePOS')`  The issue is the coorlated subqueries return the wifi only limit by it.  Since the other apps share that value, need to apply the appname filter to the outside as well

Comment: @xQbert - that did it.  I knew I was very close.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT storenumber, 
            registerid, 
            wifi_mac, 
            appname 
FROM   mpos_health.dbo.mdat_data_report AS mdat 
INNER JOIN mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
  ON mdat.wifi_mac = mpos.wifimac 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
               WHERE mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
                 AND appname = 'iMobilePOS')  
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report AS mpos 
              WHERE mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
                AND appname = 'StoreFulfill') 
  AND Appname IN ('iMobilePOS, 'StoreFulfill')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a **[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** :

```
with cte as (
  select distinct 
      storenumber
    , registerid
    , wifi_mac
    , appname 
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by wifi_mac order by AppName)
  from   mpos_health.dbo.mdat_data_report as mdat 
    inner join mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report as mpos 
      on mdat.wifi_mac = mpos.wifimac 
        and Appname in ('iMobilepos','StoreFulfill')
)
select 
      storenumber
    , registerid
    , wifi_mac
    , appname 
    , rn
  from cte o
  where exists (
    select 1 
    from cte as i
    where i.wifi_mac =o.wifimac
      and i.rn>1
      )
```

Or with a [`union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx):

```
select distinct 
    storenumber
  , registerid
  , wifi_mac
  , appname 
from   mpos_health.dbo.mdat_data_report as mdat 
  inner join mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report as mpos 
    on mdat.wifi_mac = mpos.wifimac 
      and Appname = 'iMobilepos'
where exists (
  select 1
    from mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report as mpos 
    where mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
      and appname = 'StoreFulfill'
      )

union all

select distinct 
    storenumber
  , registerid
  , wifi_mac
  , appname 
from   mpos_health.dbo.mdat_data_report as mdat 
  inner join mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report as mpos 
    on mdat.wifi_mac = mpos.wifimac 
      and Appname = 'StoreFulfill'
where exists (
  select 1
    from mpos_health.dbo.mpos_health_report as mpos 
    where mpos.wifimac = mdat.wifi_mac 
      and appname = 'iMobilepos'
      )
```